# HTML of webpage and Jsoup response are not the same

Tags: java, android, html, jsoup, html-parsing

```
Connection.Response loginResponse = Jsoup.connect("https://users.premierleague.com/accounts/login/")
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5376e Safari/8536.25 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)")
                    .data("csrfmiddlewaretoken", csrfmiddlewaretokenValue)
                    .data("login", "anand.svm99@gmail.com")
                    .data("password", "****")
                    .data("app", "plfpl-web")
                    .data("redirect_uri", "https://fantasy.premierleague.com/a/team/my")
                    .timeout(600000)
                    .cookie("auth", "token")
                    .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                    .execute();
```

I'm using the above code to login to a website using Jsoup in my Android app. But the actual HTML of the webpage after login and the response from Jsoup are different. The main body of the webpage is not found in the Jsoup response. I guess it's some security feature. I've tried different user agents and large timeout values but without luck. What shall I do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

In case of SPA (Single Page Application) DOM is not loaded but generated on fly. So page contains just a DOM root - e.g. a div and all the rest is built by JavaScript.

E.g. React based web application.

JSoup won't help in this case.

To solve check what is sent by browser and try to imitate the requests parsing responses.

Comment: I can't find the desired elements in the response. Will selenium be helpful ?

Comment: I am not a selenium expert just IMHO. Selenium should help but again you need to use browser object and use getElementByID() from browser not expecting HTML contains the tag.

Comment: thanks for that. Are you sure this website is an SPA ? How do I find it ?

Comment: I am not sure. SPA is just simplest example. Try to check how the site is built with the https://builtwith.com/?https%3a%2f%2ffantasy.premierleague.com

Comment: Another possibility could be redirect. A simple almost empty page is returned but after that user is redirected. I see redirect params. Couyld be all the content on the page where user is redirected after login.